# Kotlin: Iterate through a JSONArray

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I'm writing an Android app using Kotlin and Realm.
I have a JSONArray, and I want to iterate through the JSONObjects in this array in order to load them in a Realm database class:

Realm class:

```
import io.realm.RealmObject
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey
import io.realm.annotations.Required

open class Person(

        @PrimaryKey open var id: Long = 0,

        @Required
        open var name: String = ""

) : RealmObject() {

}
```

The JSONArray:

```
{
    "persons":[
        {
           "id":0,
           "name":"Biatrix"
        },
        {
           "id":1,
           "name":"Bill"
        },
        {
           "id":2,
           "name":"Oren"
        },
        {
           "id":3,
           "name":"Budd"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried iterating like the following:

```
for (item : JSONObject in persons) {

}
```

... but I get a `for-loop range must have an iterator() method` error.

Comment: I use the `org.json.JSONArray` and `org.json.JSONObject`.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

Unfortunately, `JsonArray` does not expose an iterator. So you will have to iterate through it using an index range:

```
for (i in 0 until persons.length()) {
    val item = persons.getJSONObject(i)

    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Nicer is: for(i in 0 until persons.length())

Comment: `for(i in 0 until persons.length()` is definitely nicer, as it seems to help avoid the dreaded off-by-one problem.  But why wouldn't an iterator be exposed?  This seems crazy by default... it's a core object type which is entirely focused upon multiple objects.  Iterating through seems only natural, right???

Comment: i got out of range exception

Comment: This is going into the wrong direction... please just remove this wrong answer. The one stating that it is easy to declare an iterator() fun yourself is much more helpful!

Answer (score 54):

Even if some class doesn't expose an `iterator` method, you can still iterate it with `for` statement by providing an extension function `iterator`:

```
operator fun JSONArray.iterator(): Iterator<JSONObject> 
    = (0 until length()).asSequence().map { get(it) as JSONObject }.iterator()
```

Now when you use `JSONArray` in `for` statement this extension is invoked to get an iterator. It creates a range of indices and maps each index to an item corresponding to this index.

I suppose the cast to `JSONObject` is required as the array can contain not only objects but also primitives and other arrays. And the `asSequence` call is here to execute `map` operation in a lazy way.

**Generic way (*assuming* all array entries are of same type)**

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
operator fun <T> JSONArray.iterator(): Iterator<T>
    = (0 until length()).asSequence().map { get(it) as T }.iterator()
```

Comment: Though of course you will not always have an array of JSONObject. You might want to try:`operator fun <T> JSONArray.iterator(): Iterator<T>
    = (0 until length()).asSequence().map { get(it) as T }.iterator()` now it has an "unchecked cast" of course.

Comment: Where is the check for an empty `JSONArray`? `get(it)` will throw an exception, if `JSONArray` is empty.

Comment: @Sevastyan `0 until length()` will produce an empty range if an array is empty, so `get` will be called 0 times (i.e. won't be called at all) on elements of the empty range.

Comment: @Ilya `0 until 0` means `0`, so `get(it)` is `get(0)`.

Comment: @Sevastyan you can quick check what `0 until 0` evaluates to with https://try.kotlinlang.org

Comment: This code assumes that the JSONArray's children are objects and only objects. Even @androidguy's suggestion assumes that the JSONArray's children are homogenous, I think.

Comment: @androidguy which can be suppressed away with `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")`

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code?

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
(0..(jsonArray.length()-1)).forEach { i ->
    var item = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
}
```

?

Comment: Can be refined as `(0 until (jsonArray.length()))`

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code?

Answer (score 4):

```
for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()){
    //do your stuff
    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 3):

shortest way is:

```
(0 until persons.length()).forEach {
    val item = persons.getJSONObject(it)
```

Basically  from a range taking from zero to the jsonarray lenght ,it takes one number at time and use it as a index to retrieve the current object

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code?