# How can I extend the JSONArray class in Kotlin with an iterator, without using Monkeypatching?

Tags: json, kotlin, constructor

I use the JSONArray class a lot in my code, and I sometimes create a new one by providing a String.

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184641/kotlin-iterate-through-a-jsonarray) to add the required functionality to the class via "monkeypatching", but I'm not allowed to do that.

So I've decided to create a custom class that extends the JSONArray and adds this method. However, I'm running into issues with the constructor, which I've resolved as follows:

```
class JSONArray(s : String? = null) : JSONArray(), Iterable<JSONObject>  {
    init {
        if(s == null) {
            JSONArray()
        } else {
            JSONArray(s)
        }
    }

    override fun iterator(): Iterator<JSONObject> {
        return (0 until length()).asSequence().map { get(it) as JSONObject }.iterator()
    }
}
```

I'm not happy with how the `init` looks. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure that your code works? Your class `JSONArray` is defined to extend itself. Also, the call to the constructor of super-class `JSONArray()` happens already in line 1. The second call in the `init` block will not have the desired effect: You are just creating a new `JSONArray`, discarding the result.

Comment: Can you explain why you cannot use the linked answer that suggests defining an extension function? What does you are "not allowed to do that" mean?

Comment: @KarstenGabriel, I'm not sure that my code works. The `JSONArray` is not defined to extend itself, rather it is just a new class with the same name. Maybe I should've named it differently. I believe the second part of your comment is correct. What I want to do, is pass on the value to the real/super `JSONArray` class. The problem is that that class has support for creating an `JSONArray` from a `String`. If I don't create the constructor, I will get an error like: `Too many arguments for public constructor JSONArray() defined in codebase.utils.JSONArray`

Comment: I am not allowed to do it that way, because I'm told that adding methods to existing classes is called 'monkeypatching', and is an antipattern because of possible future updates. That developer is not Kotlin-native, however, so they might be biased or miss the most idiomatic way to do this.

Comment: Monkeypatching changes the behaviour of a class at _runtime_. Extension functions are not monkeypatching, because they are resolved _statically_ and they do not change the behaviour of the receiver class at all. They are rather just syntactic sugar to write something like `x.f(a,b)` instead of `f(x,a,b)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you definitely do not want to define an extension function (which in my opinion would be the best solution to your problem), you can achieve what you want by providing 2 constuctors (one for each of the constructors of the super class):

```
class MyJSONArray : JSONArray, Iterable<JSONObject> {
    constructor(): super()

    constructor(x: String): super(x)

    override operator fun iterator(): Iterator<JSONObject> {
        return (0 until length()).asSequence().map { get(it) as JSONObject }.iterator()
    }
}
```

Then you can create an instance with and without a given String, but you have to choose the right constructor. If you need a function that uses the right constructor depending on a nullable value, then that could be done like this:

```
class MyJSONArray : JSONArray, Iterable<JSONObject> {
    ...
    companion object {
        fun of(x: String?) = if(x == null) MyJSONArray() else MyJSONArray(x)
    }
}
```

Then you can write `MyJSONArray.of(nullableString)` to create a JSONArray with or without a string without the need to call different constructors.

---

One big drawback of an own subclass is that you cannot use `JSONArray`s from outside your own code base in the same way as the ones you created yourself.

Another solution without creating a subclass would be to introduce helper functions that give you an iterator of a `JSONArray` without extending it:

```
fun iteratorOf(jsonArray: JSONArray): Iterator<JSONObject> =
    (0 until jsonArray.length()).asSequence().map { jsonArray.get(it) as JSONObject }.iterator()
```

In order to use this function to obtain an iterable from a `JSONArray`, we can define the following function:

```
fun iterableOf(jsonArray: JSONArray) = Iterable { iteratorOf(jsonArray) }
```

Then you can iterate through any `JSONArray` with e.g. `iterableOf(jsonArray).forEach{ ... }`.